# Not normal connected component of a right topological group

Tags: gn.general-topology, topological-groups

Let $\cal T$ be a locally compact topology on a group $G$ and $(x,y)\mapsto xy^{-1}$ be continuous at $(1,1)$ and for every $a\in G$, $x\mapsto xa$ be continuous everywhere with respect to $\cal T$.
Let $C$ be a connected component of $(G,\cal T)$ containing the neutral element $1$.

If $C$ is a normal(=invariant) subgroup of $G$ then $C$ is the intersection of all open subgroups of $G$. How if $C$ is not a normal subgroup? then is $C$ the intersection of all open subgroups of $G$?

Comment: Can this happen? Can you give examples?

Comment: @Anton It seems trivial that $C$ is a subgroup. However there is no clue for normality. No I have not any example for a not normal $C$.

Comment: It seems trivial that $C$ is a normal subgroup.

Comment: @TomDeMedts: Let $H$ be a not normal subgroup of $G$. Let $\mathcal F$ be the set of all subsets of $G$ which contain $H$. Let $\cal T$ be a topology on $G$ with $\cal F$ the set of all neighborhoods of $1$ and the maps $x\mapsto xa$ continuous everywhere. $(G,\cal T)$ is a topology as defined above. $H$ is the connected component containing $1$.

Comment: Oh, I'm sorry, I incorrectly assumed that you were considering a topological group. I should have read your title more carefully :)